# silverlight error code 2035

Tags: .net, silverlight

I want to start page with debug modus.
In this page is one silverlight application which schould show some slideshow.
Slideshow will never showed.

Im getting follow error:

```
Line: 54
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2035    
Category: ParserError       
Message: The element is not valid in the given namespace.     
File:      
Line: 2     
Position: 234
```

Its my silverlight html:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="width: 450px; height:300px">
                        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication.xap" />
                        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                        <param name="background" value="#FFFFFF" />
                        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
                        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                        <param name="location" value="ClientBin/images.xml" />
                        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
                        </a>
                        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:visible;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What at "Line: 2, Position: 234" in your XAML?

Comment: I dont know which file is it. File is not given as you see.

Comment: It will probably be in App.xaml or MainPage.xaml, but you might have t check all your code to see what's a line 2, position 234 in each of them. One of the files will have an error at that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the error has anything to do with the hosting html you provided.  Its in your Silverlight project.

Try to debug the code from the **Application_Startup()** in the **app.xaml.cs** file.

It may be because you renamed or moved an object in your project and did not update the namespaces.